# Facebook Account Kit "Send Code To Facebook" is not shown in ios devices

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, account-kit

Facebook Account Kit

I can see that there is an option for sending the code to Facebook in Android devices. However I am not getting any notification or code in Facebook app or in messenger app.

Also this option is not available in iOS devices. Is there a way to enable this option in iOS?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/ios#prerequisites refer this doc

Comment: I am able to enable the "Send Code To Facebook" button. But I am not getting any notification in Facebook account that is linked to phone number entered.

Comment: The phone number must be the primary phone number on a Facebook account. Is that the case? If it is then I'd recommend filing a bug - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/